# Should I use ACLs if I want to limit access to files on a per-group basis? If so - what's a good Java library?

Tags: java, file-permissions, acl

Not too sure if I'm barking up the right tree, so I'm wondering if ACLs are the way to go.

Comment: What kind of access: read or write? What are your groups? Please, be more specific.

Comment: Apologies - I probably should made it clearer.

I'm developing a web application (online IDE), and I'm looking for a way to represent read/write/execute permissions (not on the filesystem, but on the application) on a file based on groups that I define.

In short, I'm looking for a way to store which of my users can read this file.

Comment: Also - if it helps, it's initially going to be deployed on Windows Vista, but I'm looking to make it cross-platform, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Access Control Lists (ACLs) for file system access highly depend on the the operating system, so I really doubt there's a Java library for that.

On the other hand, Java offers ACL directly (`java.security.Acl`), so if you have an application for different users, you can use that ACL to restrict access to ressource *within* the application (which doesn't prevent a user from changing a file on the file system with his user permissions on the operating system).

Comment: Thanks. I checked out java.security.acl,but it turns out that it's deprecated, and I'm looking to represent permissions in the application, not filesystem ACLs. 
(Not your fault though, I probably should have phrased the question clearer.)

Comment: Is it? I see no such hint in the java docs for 1.5 and 1.6. For Permissions - have you found this one: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/permissions.html

Comment: Apologies - java.security.acl is apparently superseded by java.security, and not deprecated. (It does point to Permissions though!)
Great find on Permissions, will come in handy. Thanks!

Comment: (I'd upvote, but I don't have enough reputation. I wish there was some way I could acknowledge your help!)